# Wrong path is used to load NextGen Gallery assets

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

On my Wordpress website, when I go to the admin area and edit a page, all NextGen Gallery assets are loading from an incorrect path and hence 404ing.

For example the following files:

- http://example.comwp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery-pro/modules/autoupdate_admin/static/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css?ver=1.9.1
- http://example.comwp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery-pro/modules/autoupdate_admin/static/admin.css?ver=4.0.1
- http://example.comwp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ajax/static/ajax.js?ver=4.0.1

Notice how it says **`example.comwp-content`** where it should be **`example.com/wp-content`**

example.com is just a dummy name that I replaced with my real domain name.

What I've done so far with no success:

- Deactivated other plugins
- Turned error reporting on

These are the values from my wp-config.php file:

- `define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`
- `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`
- `define('WP_CONTENT_URL', '/wp-content');`
- `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

More Details:

- Wordpress Version 4.0.1
- NextGen Gallery version: 2.0.66.33
- NextGen Gallery Pro version: 2.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder):

> Set WP_CONTENT_URL to the **full** URI of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.
>
> `define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content' );`

So if you define your own `WP_CONTENT_URL`, you must use the full path. I'd say you should be using:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . '/wp-content');
```

Although, that's the default anyway, isn't it? So probably just removing that line would fix things.